# LoopBack create app error "Empty Server", how to solve this?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

Loopback NodeJS framework, I'm trying to create app and I encountered this error, can anyone help.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you should choose one of the following fields by using **arrow buttons**: *api-server, empty-server, etc*. After that press **"Enter"**.